# I need to get API key for my application and, for this, I need the MD5 signature of my certificate

Tags: java, android, avs

As seen on the Internet, I use "keytool" to get it :
    keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore keystore.jks

I type in the password android and receive the SHA1 and SHA256 signatuers. The problem is that I need an MD5 signature. I am using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

To get the MD5 and SHA1 signature of your app, click on the Gradle on the right side of your Android Studio Screen, then go to your project 'root', then to 'Tasks', then 'android', then double click on the 'signingReport'.
After you click on it, execution will take place in the 4: Run prompt, which is near the 'TODO' list. After the execution is completed, you will the desired signatures.
[Refer to the image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SW0Q.png)